# Модуль просмотра презентаций

Tags: презентации

С новогодними праздниками, леди и джентельмены!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как называется, на чем пишется модуль просмотра презентаций на сайте slideshare.net, можно ли расширить функционал модуля и как дорого это будет стоить. Пишу в праздники. Очень важно. Спасибо, и ещё раз с Рождеством.

Comment: @avtarabanov, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: [slideshare.net/developers](http://www.slideshare.net/developers) смотрели?